# making sub-menu stay open and selected when loading new page

Tags: fadein, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a main menu and one of its options has an accordion effect on toggle with the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            active: false,
            autoHeight: false,
            collapsible: true
        });
    });
});
```

When one of its sub-options is selected I add an active class with this:

```
jQuery.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(speed, easing, callback){
    return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle', width: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback);  
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#subNavUs").hide();
        $("#us").click(function () {
            $("#subNavSys").hide();
            $("#subNavApp").hide();
            $("#subNavAcc").hide();
            $("#subNavUs").slideFadeToggle(800);
            $('*').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            return true;
        });
        $("#subNavSys").hide();
        $("#sys").click(function () {
            $("#subNavUs").hide();
            $("#subNavApp").hide();
            $("#subNavAcc").hide();
            $("#subNavSys").slideFadeToggle(800);
            $('*').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            return true;
        });
```

And this triggers a sub-menu, but when I select any of this new sub-menu's options to load a new page both the accordion menu and the sub-menu are back hidden.  How can I make them stay open and show the active class I want to assign them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added "navigation: true" to the accordion function.  It was a beginner's mistake but I finally got it to work :)

I post it in case someone might have the same issue.